# Is there something like `map2 :: (i -> a) -> (i -> b) -> [i] -> [(a,b)]`?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I just wrote functions like this up to `map4` just because they seem useful:

```
map2 :: Functor f => (i -> a) -> (i -> b) -> f i -> f (a,b)
map2 f1 f2 = fmap $ \i -> (f1 i, f2 i)
```

Before I continue to `map8` i thought I'd ask if there is something similar in some standard module. Hayoo doesn't seem to know any function that has the signature above.

Note: I already found `Control.Arrow.&&&` which reduces the above to:

```
map2 f1 f2 = fmap (f1 &&& f2)
```

But there doesn't seem to be a similar function for a fanout more than two.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`(->) i` is an applicative functor, so you can write `(&&&)` as

```
f &&& g = (,) <$> f <*> g
```

and you could write `map3` as

```
map3 f1 f2 f3 = map ((,,) <$> f1 <*> f2 <*> f3)
```

except that it isn't shorter than

```
map3 f1 f2 f3 = map $ \i -> (f1 i, f2 i, f3 i)
```

But thanks to Gabriel's tip, this *is* shorter:

```
map3 f1 f2 f3 = map (liftA3 (,,) f1 f2 f3)
```

Comment: You could also use `liftA3 (,,)`

Comment: Oh nice! That is definitely better (in the sense of less writing) then .

Comment: Oh ... but `liftAn` is only defined up to `n = 3`. Having the applicative syntax sugar from Idris would be nice now.

Comment: @Florian you could use SHE for that: https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher description made me laugh ... but I prefer my Haskell clean and mean :)

Comment: Just stumbled over this old question of mine. Just wanted to drop a note that today I prefer the `f <$> a <*> b` syntax over `liftA2`. :)

Answer (score 11):

There is no standard function for a fanout more than two, although you can simulate it using nested tuples:

```
f :: i -> a
g :: i -> b
h :: i -> c

f &&& g :: i -> (a, b)

(f &&& g) &&& h :: i -> ((a, b), c)
```

If you don't like nested tuples then you will have to write this function yourself:

```
fanout3 :: (i -> a) -> (i -> b) -> (i -> c) -> i -> (a, b, c)
fanout3 f g h i = (f i, g i, h i)
```

Like you mentioned in your question, once you have such a function you can then just `map` it:

```
map (fanout3 f g h) :: [i] -> [(a, b, c)]
```

Comment: Btw ... is there something like a `Flatten` typeclass that converts things like `(a,(b,c))` to `(a, b, c)` or `[[[a],a],a]` to `[a,a,a]`. I am aware of `concat` but there seem to be a common structure there.

Comment: @Florian There isn't a `Flatten` type class that I'm aware of, but even if there were I would probably avoid it.  It would be very difficult to reason about when it would stop flattening or what the final type would be.

Comment: I guess for lists some recursive application of `concat` until the result doesn't change any more would work. (Isn't that what `fix` is about?)

Comment: @Florian `fix` wouldn't work because the type changes after each application of `concat`.  However, I would generally avoid doing something like that because it's not very idiomatic Haskell.  Also, this requires a lot of type class abuse and results in very confusing compiler errors.

Comment: Yep ... I didn't meant to use it ... this was just out of interest :)